# How do I loop through a unordered_map in C++ without auto?

Tags: c++

I am trying to loop through an unordered_map, to find if any of its VALUES is greater than 2. But this syntax is wrong

```
unordered_map<int, int> mp;
        
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    mp[arr[i]]++;
}

for (int i = 0; i < mp.size(); i++ ) {
    cout << mp[i].second << " " << endl; //mp[i].second is wrong syntax

    if (mp[i].second > 2) {
        cout << "WRONG";
        x = false;
        break;
    }
}
```

how can I do this?

Comment: Why do you think `mp[i]` has a `.second`? When `i` is an `int`, `mp[i]` is another `int`.

Comment: do you want to access the key, value ? because if all u want is the second value, it can be accessed directly through the use of ```mp[i]``

Comment: `mp[i]` is not `std::pair<int, int>` but it is `int`.

Comment: `for (const std::pair<int, int>& kvp : mp)` or `for (std::unordered_map<int, int>::const_iterator it = mp.cbegin(); it != mp.cend(); ++it)` work. `auto` does save you some typing though.

Comment: There could be situation where your map contains the keys `1` and `5`. The size will be `2` so you iterate over the keys `0` and `1`. Since `0` doesn't exist you will create it with zero as the value (and increase the size to `3`). Maps doesn't have indexes like vectors, only keys-value pairs. Either use iterators or range-for loop.

Comment: FYI -- You don't need any `for` loops to see if an item in an unordered_map is > 2.  [See this, which uses std::find_if](https://godbolt.org/z/fMh63afa4).

Comment: @OP -- *I want to search a container to see if any items are <X>*.  If you see yourself asking that question, then use `std::find` and/or `std::find_if`.  There is no need to write `for` loops to search a container for a specific item.   And for the case with `std::map` and `std::unordered_map`, if you wanted to search for a key (not the value) in the map, use the `find()` member functions of the map class.

Comment: Where does `arr` come from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you assumed(incorrectly) that `mp[i]` is `std::pair<int, int>` when in fact `mp[i]` gives you the mapped value which is of type `int` in your example. This can be seen from [`std::map::operator[]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at):

> ```
> T& operator[]( Key&& key ); (2)
> ```
>
> **Returns a reference to the value that is mapped to a key equivalent to `key`**, performing an insertion if such key does not already exist.

(emphasis mine)

---

##### Method 1

Since you don't want to use `auto`, you can explicitly write the type `std::pair<int, int>` in the *range-based for loop* as shown below:

```
//---------vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv--------------------->not using auto here as you want
for (const std::pair<const int, int> &pair_elem: mp) {
    cout << pair_elem.second << " " << endl; 
    if (pair_elem.second > 2) {
        cout << "WRONG";
        //other code here
    }
}
```

---

##### Method 2

Note that you can also use `std::find_if` instead of a for loop as shown below:

```
auto iter = std::find_if(mp.begin(), mp.end(), [](const std::pair<int,int>& elem) 
                            { return elem.second > 2;});
   if (iter != mp.end())
       std::cout << "Greater found ";
   else 
   {
       std::cout<<"Greater not found"<<std::endl;
   }
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/eTse5qdso)

Comment: You're not entirely correct: the entries of the map are `std::pair<const int, int>`s: the keys are non-modifiable. You can use `std::map<int, int>::value_type` (preferrably also introducing a type alias for `std::map<int, int>` (or `decltype(*mp.begin())`)

Comment: There's btw a compiler warning for your first code snippet because of the issue mentioned in my previous comment: https://godbolt.org/z/9c8TjTedd

Comment: @fabian Thanks for spotting that. I've added the `const` for the key in the first snippet.

Answer (score 0):

your question is missing a lot of information and literarily , if you searched on web , you would find many ways to loop over unordered_map in C++ , but anyways , here is the edited version of your code with a test case:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    const int N = 10;
    int arr[N] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
    bool x = true;

    unordered_map<int, int> mp;
    unordered_map<int, int>:: iterator it;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        mp[arr[i]]++;
    }
    mp[9] = 5;
    for (it = mp.begin(); it != mp.end(); it++) {
        cout << "key is " << it->first << " ,value is " <<  it->second << " " << endl;
        if (it -> second > 2) {
            cout << "WRONG";
            x = false;
            cout << "key is " << it->first << " ,value is " << it->second << " is greater than 2" << endl;
            break;
        }
    }


    return 0;
}
```